# How to reduce column width in a table cell{}{}?

Tags: tables, tabularray

I generated the table below using https://www.latex-tables.com/# I need the column spacing between `distractor` and `handled` reduced to a custom value. There needs to be some spacing between the main columns still so I cannot simply remove the column. What is the easiest way to do so without changing the code? I tried `cell{1}{5} = {c}{0.1cm}` but it ended up shifting `handled`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tblr}{
  cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{c},
  cell{1}{6} = {c=3}{c},
  cell{1}{10} = {c=3}{c},
  cell{1}{14} = {c=3}{c},
  cell{1}{18} = {c=3}{c},
  cell{2}{2} = {c},
  cell{2}{3} = {c},
  cell{2}{6} = {c},
  cell{2}{7} = {c},
  cell{2}{10} = {c},
  cell{2}{11} = {c},
  cell{2}{14} = {c},
  cell{2}{15} = {c},
  cell{2}{18} = {c},
  cell{2}{19} = {c},
  hline{1,9} = {-}{0.08em},
  hline{2} = {2-4,6-8,10-12,14-16,18-20}{},
  hline{3,6-7} = {-}{},
}
          & Distractor &     &      &  & Handled &     &      &  & Average &     &      &  & Accuracy &     &      &  & Human &     &      \\
method    & -1:0       & 0:2 & 0:2* &  & -1:0    & 0:2 & 0:2* &  & -1:0    & 0:2 & 0:2* &  & -1:0     & 0:2 & 0:2* &  & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2* \\
MOD       &            &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &          &     &      &  &       &     &      \\
MTGCN     &            &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &          &     &      &  &       &     &      \\
CAHMP     &            &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &          &     &      &  &       &     &      \\
Ours      &            &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &          &     &      &  &       &     &      \\
w/o clf   &            &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &          &     &      &  &       &     &      \\
w/ GT clf &            &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &         &     &      &  &          &     &      &  &       &     &      
\end{tblr}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDIT

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{-5pt} % let LaTeX figure out the best intercol. separation
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{15}{c} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distractor} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Handled} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Average} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Accuracy} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Human}   \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13} \cmidrule{14-16} 
Method & -1:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & -1:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & -1:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & -1:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & -1:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* \\
\midrule
MTGCN     & x & & & & & & & & & & & & & & x \\
CAHMP     & x & & & & & & & & & & & & & & x \\
MOD       & x & & & & & & & & & & & & & & x \\
\midrule
Ours      & x & & & & & & & & & & & & & & x \\
\midrule
w/o CLF   & x & & & & & & & & & & & & & & x \\
w/ GT CT  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 48.8 & 97.2 & 90.4 & 8.8 & 32.1 & 28.9 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 14.2 & 52.7 & 45.4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colsep  = {3pt},
                 colspec = {@{}  Q[l] 
                            *{5}{X[c, leftsep=15pt]X[c]X[c]}
                            @{}},
                 }
       \toprule
            &   Distractor 
                &   &   &   Handled 
                            &   &   &   Average 
                                        &   &   &   Accuracy 
                                                    &   &   &   Human
                                                                 &   &   \\
        \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{2-4}  \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{5-7} \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{8-10}
        \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{11-13}\cmidrule[l=-0.8]{14-16}
    method  & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2   & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    
            & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2   & 0:2*  \\
        \midrule
    MOD     &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &   
            &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
    MTGCN   &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
            &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
    CAHMP   &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
            &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
    Ours    &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
            &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
    w/o clf &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
            &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
    w/ GT cl&       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
            &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does an answer have to use a `tblr` environment? Or are you willing to entertain other solution approaches as well? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico hello, thank you for your kind offer. I definitely do not mind other solutions. Primarily worried that I am not able to understand its syntax and hence i cant fix the problem myself again in the future. This tblr environment seems intuitive for me.

Comment: A comment on a parameter setting in your second table: By setting `\setlength\tabcolsep{-5pt}`, you're actually no longer letting "LaTeX figure out the best intercol. separation". To wit, both "0.2*" and "45.4" now protrude into the right-hand margin; I can't think of anyone who would call such a situation "best".

Answer (score 1):

Your table is a bit to wide that can be nicely fit in text block. This can be solved by:

- defining wide text block as is done in MWE below
- reduce font size

**Edit(1): **
Unfortunately the content of cells in the table body is unknow, so it may be needed that smaller font size or different column types need to be used.

Regarding to your comment is now inserted more space between column  groups.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = {3pt},
             colspec = {@{}  Q[l] 
                        *{5}{X[c, leftsep=12pt]X[c]X[c]}
                        @{}},
             cell{1}{2,5,8,11,14} = {c=3}{c},
             }
   \toprule
        &   Distractor 
            &   &   &   Handled 
                        &   &   &   Average 
                                    &   &   &   Accuracy 
                                                &   &   &   Human
                                                             &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{2-4}  \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{5-7} \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{8-10}
    \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{11-13}\cmidrule[l=-0.8]{14-16}
method  & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2   & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    
        & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2   & 0:2*  \\
    \midrule
MOD     &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &   
        &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
MTGCN   &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
        &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
CAHMP   &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
        &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
Ours    &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
        &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
w/o clf &       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
        &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
w/ GT cl&       &     &         &       &       &           &   &   &
        &       &     &         &       &       &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text block borders).

**Edit (2):**
Now, when content of table is more clear, I suggest to use siunitx library/package and redesign table as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = {3pt},
             colspec = {@{}  Q[l]
                             X[c, si={table-format=1.1}, leftsep=6pt]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=1.1}]}
                             X[c, si={table-format=2.1}, leftsep=15pt]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}
                             X[c, si={table-format=2.1}, leftsep=15pt]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}
                             X[c, si={table-format=1.2}, leftsep=15pt]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}
                             X[c, si={table-format=2.1}, leftsep=18pt]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}
                        @{}},
             cell{1}{2,5,8,11,14} = {c=3}{c},
             row{1,2} = {guard}
             }
   \toprule
        &   Distractor
            &   &   &   Handled
                        &   &   &   Average
                                    &   &   &   Accuracy
                                                &   &   &   Human
                                                             &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{2-4}  \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{5-7} \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{8-10}
    \cmidrule[l=-0.8]{11-13}\cmidrule[l=-0.8]{14-16}
method  & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2   & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*
        & -1:0  & 0:2 & 0:2*    & -1:0  & 0:2   & 0:2*  \\
    \midrule
MOD     &     &     &     &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &        \\
MTGCN   &     &     &     &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &        \\
CAHMP   &     &     &     &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &        \\
Ours    &     &     &     &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &        \\
w/o clf &     &     &     &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &        \\
w/ GT cl& 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 48.8 & 97.2 & 90.8 &  8.8 & 32.1 & 28.9 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 14.2 & 52.7 & 45.4   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think the OP wants explicit, blank additional columns between the groups of three columns, though.

Comment: @Zarko thank you. How do I increase the width between the distractor and handled multicolumns? Not increase the cmidrule distance but actually push the columns away from each other. Also, where can I read what colspec = {@{} l *{15}{X[c]} @{}} stands for? I think *{15}{X[c] stands for 15 columns with center formatting but what is @{}?

Comment: @Kong, than you you just stay at your solution: revert deleted empty columns or see, if edited answer is acceptable for you. However, I do not know, if then table will fit on page. It will be much easier to help you if you would provide an example of cells contents. I suspect, that used column settings actually are not the most appropriate for your column content.

Comment: @Mico, yes, (s)he like to have more space between column groups. For this is not need to be  inserted (narrow) empty columns, sufficient is to increase `tabcolsep` as I now make in edited answer. But, what is in the cells? If in them are some numbers, than may use of the `siunitx` for their formatting are more adequate than now simple centering of contents.